# Python: How to get raw audio file using pyaudio for Google Cloud Speech API

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I am using the program given in below link on linux.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/quickstart.py

The problem I am facing is how to get my own raw audio file recorded by microphone using pyaudio to use the above program to get text of what I have recorded.

I have the below program of pyaudio but it gives me wav file. But I want to save raw audio file for google cloud speech api. I don't want to convert wav to raw audio file. I directly want to save raw audio file using pyaudio.

```
import pyaudio
import wave

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
 stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE, input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
 print "recording..."
 frames = []

 for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
 data = stream.read(CHUNK)
 frames.append(data) 
 print "finished recording"


 # stop Recording
 stream.stop_stream()
 stream.close()
 audio.terminate()

 waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
 waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
 waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
 waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
 waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
 waveFile.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer. Sorry for posting the question. I am new in programming..

```
import pyaudio
import wave

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16

CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = int(RATE / 10)
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE, input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print "recording..."
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print "finished recording"


# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()



file = open("newfile.raw", "w")
file.write(b''.join(frames))
file.close()
```

Comment: Don't excuse for asking questions, that's how we learn. Besides, you're more than welcome to answer your own questions. However, instead of just posting a code that works, please explain your solution in your answer. Thanks for helping the community!

Comment: @Rightleg Thanks for your valuable advice. I will explain the code from next time in my answer. But here the problem is I too didnt understand the code. Anyways Good Luck!.